# Is it a good idea to apply ML libraries on pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, artificial-intelligence

i am building a cognitive miner AI Bot. where My Bot has two task , one is train and other is predict.i'm using some/few ML functionalities. so here i have lots of documents(~200,000 docs) which i'm training. and then in predicting for a query, i'm following some steps to find most accurate matched document(by looking score, confidence on each document) from training. and some known functions i'm using finding like TF-IDF,n-gram,cosine-similarity of each tokens available in asked query. for doing this i am using core python , python third-party libraries,NoSQL database for keeping training data.

NOTE: all performance improvement taken care using core python as much as possible. (please don't give suggestion to use Elastic Search or python whoosh because i just want to use my silly code for another decade.:) )

I'm facing Performance issue. like to do score it is taking 2-3 seconds time. which is not good.i want that result should come in some milliseconds.

SO my question to you, if i use pandas , and try to apply all above functionality to it, will it give better performance ? or numpy matrix calculation will give better performance ?

so here i don't think code required to be paste. i just need experienced peoples view on my problem. and of course keeping in mind solution should be scalable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably won't make much of a difference either way, in terms of performance.

Pandas is extremely efficient for loading data and munging it (grouping it in different ways, pivoting, creating new columns from existing columns, and so forth).

Once your data is ready for passing to a machine learning algorithm (say, in `sklearn`), then, basically, [`pd.DataFrame.as_matrix()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html) can transform it into a numpy array, without fundamentally affecting overall performance. It's hard to conceive of any `sklearn` prediction/classification stage whose cost doesn't dominate this.

The [`sklearn-pandas` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sklearn-pandas) facilitates this even further.

If your performance isn't satisfactory at this point, the solution lies elsewhere.

Comment: thanks. one more answer want to know !! i have a task (take TF-IDF..etc) which is being used in a huge(let size 5k+) for loop . if i'll do same task in numpy matrix (you know vector operation) , will it give better performance ?

Comment: You should pass it as a numpy matrix, if possible (for both performance and other reasons).

Comment: @Achyutanandasahoo Don't worry about it. Congrats on the new rep!

Comment: Question ??? Don't you think to build numpy matrix from a huge size iterator will cost same performance ?? please correct me if i'm wrong !!

Comment: I think that the time will be small relative to the time of the TF-IDF. If you see otherwise, I'd be interested to have a look. I suggest, if that happens, that you open a new question specific for that (it's a good question). If you like, drop here a link, and I'll be glad to have a look.

Comment: asked same question. please find below link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39743567/will-a-numpy-matrix-with-complex-computation-appraoch-give-more-performance-than